# openssl not verifying signature correctly

Tags: c, openssl, rsa

Following the OpenSSL docs, I /think/ that what I'm doing is correct.. but apparently it's not. Compiling the file (with `gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -lssl sign.c`) yields no errors or warnings. `EVP_VerifyFinal()` always returns 0 (Meaning the check failed). What is causing that?

```
static const EVP_MD * type;

unsigned char * sha(char * input)
{
    EVP_MD_CTX c;
    unsigned char *md;
    unsigned int md_len;

    md = malloc(EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE);

    EVP_MD_CTX_init(&c);
    EVP_DigestInit_ex(&c, type, NULL);
    EVP_DigestUpdate(&c, input, strlen(input));
    EVP_DigestFinal_ex(&c, md, &md_len); 
    EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup(&c);

    return md;
}

unsigned char * sign(EVP_PKEY * key, unsigned char * data)
{
    EVP_MD_CTX c;
    unsigned char *sig;
    unsigned int len;

    EVP_MD_CTX_init(&c);
    sig = malloc(EVP_PKEY_size(key));

    EVP_SignInit(&c, type);
    EVP_SignUpdate(&c, data, strlen((char *)data));
    EVP_SignFinal(&c, sig, &len, key);

    EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup(&c);

    return sig;
}

int verify(EVP_PKEY * key, unsigned char * data, unsigned char * original)
{
    EVP_MD_CTX c;
    int ret;

    EVP_MD_CTX_init(&c);
    EVP_VerifyInit(&c, type);
    EVP_VerifyUpdate(&c, data, (unsigned int)sizeof(data));
    ret = EVP_VerifyFinal(&c, original, (unsigned int)strlen((char *)original), key);
    return ret;
}

int main(void)
{
    EVP_PKEY *sk, *pk;
    FILE *sfd, *pfd;
    unsigned char *hash, *sig;
    unsigned int i;

    sfd = fopen("secret.pem", "r");
    pfd = fopen("public.pem", "r");
    sk = PEM_read_PrivateKey(sfd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    pk = PEM_read_PUBKEY(pfd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    fclose(sfd);
    fclose(pfd);

    OpenSSL_add_all_digests();
    type = EVP_get_digestbyname("SHA1");

    hash = sha("moo");

    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(hash); i++)
        printf("%02x", hash[i]);
    printf("\n");

    sig = sign(sk, hash);
    switch( verify(pk, sig, hash) )
    {
        case 0:
            printf("Check failed.\n");
            break;
        case 1:
            printf("Check succeeded!\n");
            break;
        default:
            printf("Oh look, an error: %d", ERR_get_error());
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the correct size:

```
EVP_VerifyUpdate(&c, data, (unsigned int)sizeof(data));
```

Since `data` is defined as `unsigned char *`, `sizeof(data)` is probably 4 or 8 (number of bytes required to hold a pointer).

Try passing the actual number of bytes that you've allocated, i.e. `EVP_PKEY_size(key)`. You will have to pass that to your `verify()` function.

It's possible that something else is also wrong, but this one caught my eye.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but one bug could confuse users.

In the verify function original and data should be swapped, original past to EVP_VerifyUpdate and data to EVP_VerifyFinal. String length should not be used as a byte array can contain 0x00 as a valid value which will be recognized as "\0".